# How to cancel Meteor.setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to cancel a `Meteor.setTimeout` in the middle?

```
Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Start!");
}, 10000);
```

In this case, I want to use a button to cancel it in the middle of 10 seconds. Don't let it show "Start!".

If there is no way to cancel, is there any alternative way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor gives you a numeric handle to identify your timeout so you can store this to a variable

`var myTimeOutHandle = Meteor.setTimeout(function(){console.log("clearTimeout never called")}, 10000);`

and then call this inside your event on the button

`Meteor.clearTimeout(myTimeOutHandle);`